# QImage on QThreadPool fails

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qimage

I am trying to load multiple `QImage` objects from files using a threadpool. I have created my own `QRunnable` subclass to load the image from a file and copy it into a buffer:

```
class ImageLoader : public QRunnable
{
public:
    ImageLoader(const QString &filename, char **buffer, int *size) : 
        QRunnable(),
        filename(filename),
        buffer(buffer),
        size(size)
    {}

    // QRunnable interface
    void run() {
        QImage image(filename);
        (*size) = image.byteCount();
        (*buffer) = new char[(*size)];
        memcpy_s(*buffer), (*size), image.constBits(), image.byteCount());
    }

private:
    const QString filename;
    char **buffer;
    int *size;
};
```

The code works fine if executed on the main thread, but as soon as I run the runnable on a `QThreadPool`, I get a huge bunch of errors, that basically all say the same:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x2a023ae6550) is not the object's thread (0x2a023ae65c0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x2a023aca0f0)
```

The first 2 addresses change each message, I assume they represent the different threads of the pool. Whats interesting:
The first and the second are never the same, however, they are all of the same "group", i.e. the first address of the first error can become the second address of the second error etc...

The third address always stays the same, it's the address of the main (gui) thread.

Any Ideas why that happens or how to fix it? I read the documentation of `QImage` but wasn't able to find anything about threads in there, except:

> Because QImage is a QPaintDevice subclass, QPainter can be used to draw directly onto images. When using QPainter on a QImage, the painting can be performed in another thread than the current GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Is solved the problem myself:

The path I passed to the `QImage` was invalid. I don't know how this was able to produce such an error, but after I fixed the path, it works just fine!